# PromQL query to find the duration of each firing alert

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql, grafana-variable

I am creating a Grafana dashboard to see the total alert count for each firing alert and the duration ( means it should capture how long alerts have been firing state).

PromQL query used to capture the total alert count is as follows,

`count by (alertname,customerName) (changes(customer_ALERTS[24h]))`

Idea is to add two more column in the Grafana table panel having the `alert count` and the `duration`

Now i need to get the query to capture the duration for each alerts. Can somebody please share some thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

If you know the evaluation interval for alerts, then the following PromQL query could be used for calculating the duration in seconds for alerts in firing state over the last 24 hours:

```
count_over_time(customer_ALERTS[24h]) * <evaluation_interval_in_seconds>
```

The query assumes that `customer_ALERTS` contains non-empty values when alert is firing and has no any values when the alert isn't firing. If the `customer_ALERTS` contains `zero` values when the alert isn't firing and `one` values when the alert is firing, then the following query should be used instead for determining the duration of alerts in firing state in seconds:

```
avg_over_time(customer_ALERTS[24h]) * 24 * 3600
```

If `customer_ALERTS` contains other values for firing / not firing state, then [PromQL subqueries](https://valyala.medium.com/prometheus-subqueries-in-victoriametrics-9b1492b720b3) could be used for counting samples in firing state. Take a look also at [MetricsQL functions](https://victoriametrics.github.io/MetricsQL.html) such as `lifetime(m[d])`,   `share_gt_over_time(m[d], gt)` or `count_gt_over_time(m[d], gt)`.

Comment: Thanks. I used the second query  and  i see the value for all the alerts is 8600.
`(avg_over_time(customer_ALERTS{alertstate="firing",severity="critical"}[24h])) *24 * 3600`
any reason why the value is same?

Comment: could you look at the graph for `customer_ALERTS{alertstate="firing",severity="critical"}` for the last day? The `avg_over_time()` query expects that the graph has no gaps and contains 0 values when the alert wasn't firing and 1 values when the alert was firing as outlined in the answer.